# resize background image inside div

Tags: css, html

I really need some help with this issue. I'm struggeling with it since a few days and can't figure out how to solve. I checked this site already for an answer, but couldn't fix my issues with the answers provided.

I'm using the skeleton 960 grid for a new website.

I'm creating a one-page website and this is my code for the trouble section:

```
<div id="section-offerte"></div>
 <div id="page-offerte">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="sixteen columns">
    <div class="title-test">
     <h1>OFFERTE</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="fifteen columns"></div>
 </div><!-- container -->
</div><!--end page offerte-->
```

and my css:

```
#page-offerte {
    height: 700px;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.container .fifteen.columns {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 491px;
    float: left;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url(images/bg-offerte.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
/* Note: Design for a width of 320px */
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.container {
    width: 300px;
}
.container .columns, .container .column {
    margin: 0;
}
.container .fifteen.columns {
    width: 320px;
}
/* Note: Design for a width of 480px */
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {
 .container {
width: 420px;
}
 .container .columns, .container .column {
margin: 0;
}
 .container .fifteen.columns {
width:420px;
}
```

Comment: what's the issue exactly?

Comment: sorry, when i read my message, i saw i was forget to mention it. The problem is, that the background-image does not scale with the div. It's cut instead of resizing to the width and height of the div. Hope I'm clear.

Comment: you should use `background-size:contain` for your **div** not `background-size:cover`

Comment: WOW ABFORCE! You saved my day!! Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `contain` instead of `cover`.

```js
function smallIt() {
  var img = document.getElementById("foo");
  img.style.width = "200px";
  img.style.height = "200px";
}
```

```css
#foo {
  background: url("http://placekitten.com/300/300");
  background-size: contain;
  border: groove;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo"></div>
<button onclick="smallIt()">Small it</button>
```